# MSSQL varchar(max) 50 seconds for one record to insert

Tags: sql-server, blob, varchar, varcharmax

Hi i have a table with field i need to store a text/json/xml into. If i insert just one record with a length of about 20MByte it takes forever about 50 seconds.
The table is defined like this

```
table {
  ID: integer autoincrement primaryindex
  Data: varchar(max)
}
```

What can be done to optimize this. I hope to get it to instant inserts

Comment: "Instant" is too ambitious, because no matter how you store it, your client has to transfer that 20 MiB of data to the server. But assuming you have a decent network connection and a good I/O system for the database, fast inserts should be possible. The big questions are 1) how do you generate the text and 2) what code are you using to do the insert? The worst way of measuring this is by using Management Studio, which is not geared toward handling large values at all.

Comment: as Jeroen has mentioned, we need to see the insert statement but I would say we also need to see the output of SET STATISTICS IO ON and also paste the execution plan to https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/

Comment: Thx for the fast answers. It seems it's the problem of our Azure level of SQL. Server.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look over the size of your database files (date and transactions log). You needs to have wide amout of free pages in the files to avoid autoextension that causes time to do so.

A +